# Handling generic class members when there is no generic type variable defined in class

Tags: java, generics

Please have a look at the following code:

```
public class MyClass<T extends MyObject> {
    private Class<T> clazz;
    public void setClass1(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
    public Class<T> getClass1() {
        return clazz;
    }
    public T getObject1() {
        T o = null;
        try {
            o = clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return o;
    }
}
```

The above works great but requires the class type `T` to be known before any `MyClass` object is created. Now if I want to delay specifying `T` until `setClass1()` is ever called, I have to remove `<T extends MyObject>` from `MyClass` declaration to something like below:

```
public class MyClass {
//  private Class<T> clazz; // doesn't work anymore as T is unknown, so do the following instead
    private Class<? extends MyObject> clazz;
    public <T extends MyObject> void setClass1(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz; // OK
    }
    public void setClass2(Class<? extends MyObject> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz; // OK
    }
    public <T extends MyObject> Class<T> getClass1() {
        return clazz; // Error, need casting to Class<T>
    }
    public Class<? extends MyObject> getClass2() {
        return clazz; // OK
    }
    public <T extends MyObject> T getObject1() {
        T o = null;
        try {
            o = clazz.newInstance(); // Error, must cast to T
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return o;
    }
    public MyObject getObject2() {
        MyObject o = null;
        try {
            o = clazz.asSubclass(MyObject.class).newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return o; // OK, but lost the difference between ? extends MyObject and MyObject
    }
}
```

First, why `getClass1()` gives error, while `setClass1()` is OK?

Second, why the return in `getObject1()` must be cast to `(T)`?

Third, how do you fix `getObject1()` without unnecessary casting nor `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`?

Fourth, in my case would changing from using `setClass1()`, `getClass1()`, `getObject1()` to `setClass2()`, `getClass2()`, `getObject2()` better?

Comment: **If** "_requires the class type T to be known before any MyClass object is created_" is the problem (which might be not if this is just thinking about generics and not real code), how about implementing a constructor then? `public MyClass(Class<T> clazz) { setClass1(clazz); }` None of the methods are `static` so you still need to instantiate `MyClass` before calling `setClass1()` anyway...

Comment: Thanks. But `MyClass` has more methods that I use that do not depend on the class type and I may not even have to call any `setClass()` nor `getClass()` at all for the lifetime of the `MyClass` instance.

Comment: Hmmmm looks like a design problem, then. If you have a class with fields and methods that have _nothing_ to do with other fields and methods, then you actually have _two_ classes, not one.

Comment: @walen That wouldn't help neither. It just pushes the issue forward for I still need to have an instance of the other class in `MyClass` which is going to be declared as `MyTypedClass<? extends MyObject> myTypedClass` and `class MyTypedClass<T extends MyObject>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Class<? extends MyObject> clazz;

public <T extends MyObject> void setClass1(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz; // OK
}
```

In this example, `clazz` is defined as a reference that can hold *any* kind of Class objects that are of some unknown type that is a subclass of `MyObject`.

The *any* part is important. This is why `setClass1` works since it assigns effectively the same thing to `clazz` - a subtype of `MyObject`. Because of this, the compiler will not complain.

Your method `setClass1` is effectively a more generic version of this method:

```
public void setClass3(Class<MyObject> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz; // OK
}
```

since `setClass3` assigns the most concrete type `Class<MyObject>` to `clazz`, which can hold *any* Class that is `MyObject` or a subclass of it.

Moving on.

```
  public <T extends MyObject> Class<T> getClass1() {
        return clazz; // Error, need casting to Class<T>
  }
```

This will not work since `T` is a subclass of `MyObject`, but can you be certain that `clazz` holds `Class<MyObject>` or `Class<T>` for some value of T?

For example, imagine you also have these classes defined somewhere:

```
public class MySubObject1 extends MyObject {...}
```

and

```
public class MySubObject2 extends MyObject {...}
```

Imagine that the wildcard type `?` represents `MySubObject1` while `T` represents `MySubObject2` and since they bear no relationship to each other, the compiler will complain. Remember, you cannot do this:

```
    MySubObject1 so1 = new MySubObject2(); // compiler error

    MySubObject2 so2 = new MySubObject1(); // compiler error
```

A similar problem exists in `getObject1` - the compiler cannot know that `T` represents a class or a superclass of `clazz` (remember it can hold any subclass of `MyObject`), that's why the casting is necessary.

With your current design, you cannot really avoid casting and `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` in `getObject1`. If possible, try to avoid mixing generic types and wildcards.

One more thing. `getClass2` forces its users to deal with a wildcard - not a great API design decision.

Methods in your `public class MyClass` class have potential type safety issues.

Are you sure that your original `public class MyClass<T extends MyObject>` class doesn't meet your needs? It looks fine to me, except the `clazz.newInstance();` part since it requires `MyObject` and every one of its subclasses to have a zero argument constructor.

Comment: Thanks heaps! Very detailed explanation. So if casting is unavoidable I will go for it. I did not want to use wildcard too but since removing `<T extends MyObject>` from `MyClass` causes the `Class<T> clazz` declaration failed, I am forced to use `Class <? extends MyObject> clazz` instead.

Answer (score 2):

> First, why getClass1() gives error, while setClass1() is OK?

In `setClass()` you assign a `Class<? extends MyObject>` to a variable of type `Class<? extends MyObject>`. That is allowed.

In `getClass()`, you want to retrieve a `Class<T>` from a variable of type `Class<? extends MyObject>`. But the compiler has no way to know if what is stored in the variable is really a `Class<T>` or perhaps a `Class<U>`. So this is forbidden.

> Second, why the return in getObject1() must be cast to (T)?

`Class<? extends MyObject>.newInstance()` returns an object of type `? extends MyObject`. This is not the same as `T`. That's why you have to cast.

> Third, how do you fix getObject1() without unnecessary casting nor @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")?

As explained, the version above does not contain an *unnecessary* cast. You either have to make `T` a generic parameter of the class itself or you need the cast.

Comment: Thanks. But `setClass1()` is assigning a `Class<T>` to `Class<? extends MyObject>`

Comment: @user1589188 In your second example, you're declaring `clazz` as `Class<? extends MyObject>`. Since `T extends MyObject`, you can assign `Class<T>` to `clazz`, but its type would still be `Class<?>`. So that's the only thing you can `get()` without casting it first to something more specific. It's the whole "_a Car is-a Vehicle, but a Vehicle can be a Car, or a Motorbike, or a Plane..._" thing.